# Oracle ADF turn shared library on or off

Tags: deployment, oracle-adf, weblogic12c

My team has a number of Oracle ADF applications.  For consistency and convenience, every page includes a common library .jar, that contains a number of things like page templates, a common Application Module to extend from, common bases classes to extend from (e.g., for things like `ApplicationModuleImpl` or `ViewRowImpl` classes).

For deployment, I found myself faced with two choices.  One: I could have each page include a private copy of the common .jar, which would keep updates to the common .jar from breaking existing pages, but which would require every page to be updated and redeployed in order to pick up the common .jar updates.  Or, two: I could have each page refer to a single, external copy of the common .jar, which would be the reverse (i.e., all pages pick up common .jar updates immediately, but that can break them if we make a mistake).

What I really want is a way in the WebLogic Server deployment to change the source of the common .jar being used, on the fly.  E.g., have all applications using the common, external .jar, but be able to switch individual applications to go back to using their private copy of the .jar, if needed.

I hope that's clear.  Does anyone know how to do that in an ADF application deployment on WebLogic?

Answer (score 0):

*Not sure if below will work, never tested, but you can try*

You can copy the common JAR in weblogic domain's "lib" folder which will mean it can be referred to by all of your applications. This will solve the purpose of using common.jar from a common location for all apps. Now, if you want a particular application to use a different version of the same JAR, then you can package that version with the application itself. This will mean that at runtime, the application will first search its own packaged JARs for the IMPL classes, if not found, it will search in the common JAR placed in lib folder.

Comment: I think the point of my question must have been unclear.  I know how to user either a common .jar or a private (packaged) .jar.  What I want to be able to do is deploy applications that will use the common .jar by default, but that I can switch on the fly to start using their private (package) .jar, without having to redeploy the application to make the swtich.